# Bash CURL to php

Tags: php, curl

I have some trouble with translate bash curl to PHP. Look's it is not working for me. I don't know how to check it is correct code.

```
curl -X "POST" "https://someurl.com/oauth/token" \
 -H "Authorization: Basic eyJ...V6w" \
 --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
 --data-urlencode "scope=api" \
 --data-urlencode "username=user@example.uri" \
 --data-urlencode "password=p...d"
```

I have tryied with that:

```
$query1 = urlencode("grant_type=password");
$query2 = urlencode("scope=api");
$query3 = urlencode("username=login@mail.com");
$query4 = urlencode("password=loginpass");


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someurl.com/oauth/token&".$query1."&".$query2."&".$query3."&".$query4."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ZnVydGFzdGljLTZhMTAzNTE4Y2YyOGNhNmI3OTNhYzljNmJjM";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "</pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Have you tried with some php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way. Keep in mind that you are posting the parameters. So the query string should not be attached to the URL but sent as post parameters

```
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'scope' => 'api',
    'username' => 'user@example.uri',
    'password' => 'p...d'
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someurl.com/oauth/token");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ZnVydGFzdGljLTZhMTAzNTE4Y2YyOGNhNmI3OTNhYzljNmJjM";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query($data));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);


echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
```